# Ipod Classic 160g not showing music after sync with Rythmbox running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sync, music, rhythmbox, ipod

I have an Ipod classic, running Ubuntu 18.04. I have formatted the Ipod, synced it in Rythmbox and can see the playlist and can play the playlist in Rythmbox, but when unplugging it, there is no music indicated on the ipod.
I have tried all 3 ways of formatting. Clearly it stores the music, but does not recognize it there.